# regular expression that matches the below pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm not good in regular expression, but today I faced an unavoidable situation, So I need a regular expression that matches the case below:

```
|hhas.jpg||sd22-9393das.png||8jjas.png||IMG00338-20110109.jpg|
```

I tried this regex : `/(?<=\|)(\w|\d+\.\w+)(?=\|)/i` but not getting the desired results...

I want to match all the strings  by using `preg_match` function of PHP between two `|` signs ie hhas.jpg, sd22-9393das.png etc...

Comment: What undesired result are you getting?

Comment: wHEN I TRIED THIS /(?<=\|).+(?=\|)/i  ,I GET Array ( [0] => b2.png||b3.jpg||b5.jpg

Comment: What I need is Array ([0]=>hhas.jpg [1]=>sd22-9393das.png [2]=>8jjas.png[3]=>IMG00338-20110109.jpg

Comment: Please see both answers.

Comment: @user3041943 I would just split using `preg_split()` with `~\|+~`. After that you only need to get rid of empty values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

`/\|([^|]*)\|/gi`

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/mK5gN1)

Matched strings:

```
1. hhas.jpg
2. sd22-9393das.png
3. 8jjas.png
4. IMG00338-20110109.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this..

```
preg_match_all('/\|(.*?)\||/', $str, $matches);
print_r(array_filter($matches[1]));
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hhas.jpg
    [1] => sd22-9393das.png
    [2] => 8jjas.png
    [3] => IMG00338-20110109.jpg
)
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/145262)</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your expression :

```
/(?<=\|)(\w|\d+\.\w+)(?=\|)/i
```

pretty well written , but just has a few minor flaws

- when you say `\w` that is only one character.
- the `OR` condition
- `\d+\.\w+` will match only when it meets the same order. i.e. list of digits first followed by a `.` and then followed by letters or digits or underscore.

better change your regex to :

```
/(?<=\|)(.*?)(?=\|)/ig
```

this will give you anything which is between `|`s

also IMHO , using lookarounds for such a problem is an overkill. Better use :

```
/\|(.*?)\|/ig
```

Answer (score 1):

Try without using regular expression.

```
explode('||', rtrim(ltrim ('|hhas.jpg||sd22-9393das.png||8jjas.png||IMG00338-20110109.jpg|','|'),'|'));
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => hhas.jpg [1] => sd22-9393das.png [2] => 8jjas.png [3] => IMG00338-20110109.jpg )
```

Comment: That would not suffice for the case '|a||b||c|d|e|', but I don't know if the OP needs to handle those cases aswell.